# Regex expression to allow MM:SS,TH or SS,TH

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex that will allow the input of a time in minutes, seconds, tenths & hundredths.
The problem I have is that the user should also be allowed to enter a time in just seconds & tenths or seconds, tenths & hundredths. The variations are like this:

mm:ss:th
m:ss:th
mm:s:t

You get the picture.

The following allows ss:th | ss:t | s:th | s:t

`^(([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])(\.|\,)([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]))$`

However, as soon as I add the minutes into the expression, the validation always fails:

`^(([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])(\.|\,)([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])) | (([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])(\.|\,)([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]))$`

Eventually I need to also add hours and also allow a user to enter a time in seconds more than 59 - e.g. 67.32s

Comment: Do you need to separately capture the minutes, seconds, tens, and hundredths?

Comment: Language is irrelevant - I have (\.|,) to deal with decimal issue

Comment: @CraigMorgan: He meant the programming language - regex features vary wildly between languages.

Comment: I need to allow pretty much all time variations that could be entered in an athletics meeting. hh:mm:ss.th. Example - 1:15:2.76  or 1:15:02,76  or 01:15:02,76. You can ignore the hours (hh) for now as I guess as soon as the problem mentioned in the description is solved, it should be easy to add them in.

Comment: Language - duh! My bad. Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There maybe unaccounted formats the following doesn't cover :)

```
^(?:\d+:)?(?:[0-5]\d:|[0-9]:)?(?:[0-5]\d|\d)(?:[.,]\d\d?)?$
```

Succeeds and fails for the following:

```
9.45  -  success
9  -  success
4:6.65  -  success
5:06.65  -  success
5:6,65  -  success
50:40  -  success
50:40.65  -  success
50:06.65  -  success
50:06.6  -  success
06.65  -  success
6.65  -  success
1:50:06.65  -  success
19:50:06.65  -  success
19:50:06.65  -  success
69,45  -  fail
69.45  -  fail
19:60:06.65  -  fail
19:50:96.65  -  fail
```

I'll type up an explanation shortly.

REVISED - based on OP's comment

```
^(?:\d+:)?(?:[0-5]\d:|[0-9]:)?(?:[0-5]\d|\d|^\d\d)(?:[.,]\d\d?)?$
```

Where it previous failed for `69,45|69.45` it now matches. I just added in the seconds portion:

```
|^\d\d
```

Of course it'll fail for `169,45` but just change previous addition to:

```
|^\d+
```

Now it'll match what ever amount of seconds :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have been trying to add one more criteria but it is not working. It should be possible to enter a time in seconds over 59.99, but only if there are no hours involved. 1:66.34 should not be allowed but 66.34 should. This is what I tried: `^(?:(?:\d+:)?(?:[0-5]\d:|[0-9]:)?(?:[0-5]\d|\d)(?:[.,]\d\d?)?)|(?:\d\d\d[.,]\d\d)?$`

Comment: @CraigMorgan please check revised regex

Answer (score 1):

Let's stick to legal values for now (it's always possible to relax the requirements later), and let's use a verbose regex, hoping your regex flavor supports those:

```
^          # Start of string
(?:        # Match the following non-capturing group:
 (         # Match (and capture into group 1):
  \d{1,2}  # one or two digits
 )         # End of group 1
 :         # Match a colon
)?         # End of non-capturing group, make it optional.
(          # Start of capturing group 2:
 [0-5]?    # Match a number between 0 and 5 (optional)
 [0-9]     # Match a number between 0 and 9 (required)
)          # End of group 2
:          # Match a colon
([0-9])    # Match and capture a number (0-9) in group 3
(?:        # Match the following non-capturing group:
 ([0-9])   # Match and capture a number in group 4
)?         # End of non-capturing group (optional)
$          # End of string
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/mU0gG9).

Edit: JavaScript doesn't support verbose regexes, so you need this:

```
/^(?:(\d{1,2}):)?([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-9])(?:([0-9]))?$/.test(subject)
```

to get a True/False answer if `subject` matches the requirements.

Comment: OK - that works... thanks. Just so that I can understand and extend your solution to include the decimals and the hours, can you please explain what this means - (?:        # Match the following non-capturing group:

Comment: @CraigMorgan: `(?:...)` is the same as `(...)` with one difference: The part matched by the contents of the group is only remembered for later reuse/extracting by the latter. See this tutorial on [(non-)capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: It should be nicer if `[0-9]` are replaced by `\d`.