# Extend regex expression to include the time format sss,th

Tags: javascript, regex

This is an extension of this question: [Regex expression to allow MM:SS,TH or SS,TH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429502/regex-expression-to-allow-mmss-th-or-ss-th)

I need to extend the regex to include a time that is only in seconds. For example a (slow) 400m run will could be timed as 63.43.

The expression `^(?:\d+:)?(?:[0-5]\d:|[0-9]:)?(?:[0-5]\d|\d)(?:[,]\d\d?)?$` as answered in the previous question covers all the following times:
0:59
12:34:56
12:34:5,4
1:2:3,56
1:23,45
1:2,12

My attempt at extending it failed:

`^(?:\d+:)?(?:[0-5]\d:|[0-9]:)?(?:[0-5]\d|\d)(?:[.]\d\d?)?|(?:\d{1,3})(?:[,.]\d)(?:\d)?$`

I have added it to [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/yG6iZ2)

I really can't seem to get my head round regular expressions!

Comment: You might want to try unrestricting this to allow programmatic validation if you're going to allow for so many versatile formats.

Comment: Yeah, you risk having a single regex becoming an unreadable, unmaintainable mess if you keep adding special cases to it. I agree that you should break it up into a number of distinct formats, testing against each one until you get a match. For the new case, it sounds like `\d+` for the seconds column (and forbid a minutes column) would do the trick.

Comment: Edit: Added tag javascript, assuming the same as previous question on the same topic.

Comment: Yes I thought about breaking it up an I may just do this as the only case where I will need seconds more than 60 is in the 400m race.

Comment: @Phil: As far as I am concerned - ALL regex is unreadable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this regex ?

```
 ^(?:(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}))?(?::?(\d{1,3}))?(?:[.,](\d{1,3}))?$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/iQ5oF8

#### Discussion

This regex is quite permissive. It allows values like this:

```
 99:99:999.999 <-- 
 ^  ^  ^  ^
 |  |  |  |
 HH |  |  |
    MM |  |
       SS |
          , is allowed also
```

Tell me if you need a more restrictive and/or different regex.

Comment: Many thanks - awesome answer. What should not be allowed is a time in seconds over 59.99 when minutes are added. For example 62.56 is OK. 162.56 is also OK although unlikely ever to be required unless it's my granny running the 400. 1:62.56 should NOT be allowed.

Comment: @CraigMorgan When you see this `1:2`, is it `1 hour and 2 minutes` or `1 minute and 2 seconds` ?

Comment: That would be one hour and 2 minutes. One hour 2 seconds would be 1:0:2